# While trying to delete address its redirecting to 404 page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, shipping-address, delete

When I try to delete additional address in Magento 2 customer dashboard its redirecting to 404 Page. My URL format mentioned below.

```
/customer/address/delete/id/13/form_key/xkTKVSSxqip79bZ1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution. Change **`'HttpPostActionInterface'`** with **`'HttpGetActionInterface'.`**

> vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Address/delete.php
>   use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;
>
> class Delete extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Address implements HttpGetActionInterface

Comment: Interestingly even with `HttpPostActionInterface`, it works from `grid` delete URL but not from the edit form section.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what version of Magento 2 you are.

See [this commit on GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blame/1e0fa4d299a160260e9a7162e3f950277d16ecbd/app/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/System/Design/Delete.php#L17). It added a check to enforce the request to be done with `POST` method. The [default js code](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/7bf6f187c4718ccde9570240f6dd34b8832542af#diff-18d2bad6218c4c0d666ccc4b65435348) will send the request trough a `POST` request.

I don't see why your code does not work or how you're calling that GET request. But I would recommend simply changing your template to use a form instead of an anchor element.

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getUrl("*/*/delete") ?>" method="POST">
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $_address->getId() ?>">
    <button type="submit">
        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Delete')) ?>
    </button>
</form>
```

Obviously some styling will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use preference :

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Address\Delete" type="Vendor\AddressDelete\Controller\Customer\Delete" />
</config>
```

Create a custom module and override this class,

```
namespace Vendor\AddressDelete\Controller\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;

class Delete extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Address implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $addressId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);

        if ($addressId && $this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            try {
                $address = $this->_addressRepository->getById($addressId);
                if ($address->getCustomerId() === $this->_getSession()->getCustomerId()) {
                    $this->_addressRepository->deleteById($addressId);
                    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You deleted the address.'));
                } else {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__('We can\'t delete the address right now.'));
                }
            } catch (\Exception $other) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($other, __('We can\'t delete the address right now.'));
            }
        }
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/index');
    }
}
```